# Dynamic Heroicons import with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using heroicons in my Next.js project and since it currently doesn't support dynamic imports (by passing icon name to component) I created my own component.

```js
// HeroIcon.tsx
import * as SolidIcons from '@heroicons/react/solid';
import * as OutlineIcons from '@heroicons/react/outline';

interface Props {
  icon: string;
  color?: string;
  size?: number;
  outline?: boolean;
}

export const HeroIcon = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const { icon, color, size, outline = false } = props;

  const { ...icons } = outline ? OutlineIcons : SolidIcons;

  // @ts-ignore
  const Icon: JSX.Element = icons[icon];

  const classes = [
    `${color ? color : 'text-black'}`,
    `h-${size ? size : 6}`,
    `w-${size ? size : 6}`
  ];

  return (
    // @ts-ignore
    <Icon className={classes.join(' ')} />
  );
};
```

and I can later use it as such:

```js
<HeroIcon icon='CogIcon' color='text-blue-600' size={6} outline />
```

---

While it works on my development server:
[image]

the moment I build the project with `npm run build` and start it with `npm start` I'm getting this result instead:
[image]

and on mobile devices, icons are not visible at all.

The page is pre-rendered with SSG and uses both `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`.

**Any idea what might be the reason?**

Answer (score 2):

This code is the problem

```js
  const classes = [
    `${color ? color : 'text-black'}`,
    `h-${size ? size : 6}`,
    `w-${size ? size : 6}`
  ];
```

If you want to change Tailwind CSS styles dynamically, write your code like this instead.

```js
  const classes = [
    `${color ? color : 'text-black'}`,
    size ? 'h-12' : 'h-6',
    size ? 'w-12' : 'w-6',
  ];
```

This is due to how Purge CSS works, and Tailwind CSS uses Purge CSS under the hood to optimize your Tailwind CSS classes for production.

Sadly, you cannot write your class like `h-{x}`, since Tailwind CSS is purged at build time and `h-{x}` does not evaluate to valid Tailwind CSS class.

---

**Reference**
https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @brandon-julio-thenaro's answer,
here is another cool way of implementing this using the [`tailwind-merge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) library:

```
// HeroIcon.tsx
import * as SolidIcons from '@heroicons/react/24/solid';
import * as OutlineIcons from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge';

enum IconType {
  outline = 'outline',
  solid = 'solid',
}

interface DynamicHeroIconProps {
  icon: string;
  type?: IconType;
  className?: string;
}

export const DynamicHeroIcon = (props: DynamicHeroIconProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { icon, className, type = 'outline' } = props;

  const { ...icons } = type === 'outline' ? OutlineIcons : SolidIcons;

  // @ts-ignore
  const Icon: JSX.Element = icons[icon];

  const c = twMerge('h-6 w-6 text-black', className);

  return (
    // @ts-ignore
    <Icon className={c} />
  );
};
```

This way allows you to satisfy PurgeCSS requirement, while keeping the component widely overridable.

Answer (score 0):

As it is pointed out already, PurgeCSS wont allow string interpolated class names.

Instead one could provide list of default styles, which optionally could be overridden.

Below is type-safe, compact form with minimal dependencies:

```
// heroicon-named.ts[x] - tsx is optional, since JSX syntax is not used
import { createElement } from 'react'
import * as solid from '@heroicons/react/24/solid'
import * as outline from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'

export function HeroIconNamed<T extends 'solid' | 'outline' = 'solid'>(props: {
  name: T extends 'solid' ? keyof typeof solid : keyof typeof outline
  type?: T
  className?: string
}) {
  const { name, type, className: overrides } = props
  // latest classes override the defaults
  const className = ['h-6', 'w-6', 'text-black']
    .concat(overrides?.split(' ') || []).join(' ')
  const icon = { solid, outline }[type ? type : 'solid'][name]
  // no need to use JSX syntax for "dynamically" acquired component
  return createElement(icon, { className })
}
```

When using:

```
// my-icon.tsx
import { HeroIconNamed } from './heroicon-named'

const MyIcon = () =><HeroIconNamed
  type={'solid'}
  name={'Bars2Icon'}
  className="text-[#65a30d]" />
```

LSP enabled IDE with code completion will assist selecting name of icon.